# Query in inner product axioms in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, complex-numbers

In inner product spaces in $\mathbb R$ we have an axiom stating that:
$$ \langle x, x\rangle \geq 0\ \ \text{and}  \ \  \langle x, x\rangle = 0 \iff x = 0$$

In Griffiths' textbook for Quantum Mechanics, they have stated that,

$$ \langle\alpha|\alpha\rangle \geq 0\ \ \text{and}  \ \  \langle\alpha|\alpha\rangle = 0 \iff x = 0$$

My question is that, since $\alpha \in \mathbb C$ then why is true that $\langle\alpha|\alpha\rangle \geq 0$. the product of two complex number can be negative, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complex numbers, the inner product is $\sum_i\bar {a_i} b_i$ rather than  $\sum_i a_i b_i$, where $\bar {a_i}$ denotes the complex conjugate.

Note that if $a=x+iy$ then $\bar a \cdot a=x^2+y^2\ge0$

Comment: Ahha, I see. I missed that point, damn. So, $|\psi\rangle^*$ becomes $\langle \psi|$ and then you take the product.

Comment: @Manu yes, for more general "states" you have to take the conjugate of the dual vector, so one ket turns into a bra.

Answer (score 1):

$|\alpha\rangle$ is a state, not a number. The rules of inner product state that
$$
\langle \beta |\alpha \rangle \in {\mathbb C} , \qquad \langle \beta |\alpha \rangle^* = \langle \alpha |\beta \rangle.
$$
It follows that
$$
\langle \alpha |\alpha \rangle^* = \langle \alpha | \alpha \rangle \quad \implies \quad \langle \alpha | \alpha \rangle \in {\mathbb R}. 
$$
We can therefore assign a sign to this quantity. Another rule for QM then requires that the inner product be positive semi-definite,
$$
\langle \alpha |\alpha \rangle \geq 0 , \qquad \langle \alpha |\alpha \rangle = 0 \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad |\alpha\rangle = 0 . 
$$